# What are the hours of operation of the Ankara Metro?

Tags: trains, public-transport, ankara

What are the times of the first and last trains on the Ankara Metro?

(By "metro", I mean both lines, even though I believe technically only one of them has the official title of 'metro'.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ankaray](http://www.ankaray.com.tr/yolcu-hizmetleri/sefer-bilgileri.html):
6:00 to 23:50
(time of departure from each terminus, arrival 15–20 minutes later at the end station, if I understand the automatic translation from Turkish correctly)

[Ankara Metrosu](http://www.ankarametrosu.com.tr/isthareketsaat.html):
6:00 to 23:40
(time of departure from each terminus, with an extra train from Kızılay 0:20 to Ostim 0:40)

Comment: The times of departure are different depending on the direction. These times are only for a single direction for each line.